# Unregister a DLL on a Pocket PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compact-framework, pocketpc

I demoed a control (from MooseWorks) for my Pocket PC app.  I used the demo control in my app to see if it would work.

It worked great and we have now purchased it. I took the old (demo) dll out of my project and added the new one in. I also deleted it off the device and did a clean build.  But the demo dll (with a nag screen) is still being used.

Has the demo one been registered on the device somehow?  Is there a way to un-register it?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually register and unregister dlls using the `regsvrce.exe` tool - this comes with visual studio or the platform SDK, but this doesn't sound like your problem. Are you sure you have replaced the demo version with the registered version on the device? Maybe you need to register the new version correctly? Otherwise, I would check with the vendor, they will be able to help you more easily.